# How to use SVM with video data?

Tags: video, svm

My problem is how to classify two actions: running and walking using the SVM method.
First I have 02 videos (the first action is running, the 2nd one is walking), after, I've transformed them into a sequence of binary images MC and MM (I have used the Contour detection ie: the 02 matrices contain only 1 and 0).

- **MC**: is a matrix of dimension (120 * 160 * 65), 65 is "number of frames of the first video.
- **MM**: is a matrix of dimension (120 * 160 * 87), 87 is "number of frames of the 2nd video.

Issues:

1. How can i use SVM? How can form my data matrix and my groups vector?
2. Should I use directly the matlab commands `svmtrain`, `svmclassify` and adapt them to my problem or I have to write my own code?
3. Is `svmsacling` important in my case?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use SVM to classify the videos
1) You need to select  feature descriptor/s (feature extraction). For example, if the background is static, when a person runs, the number of the pixel may be larger than the case where the person walks. Selecting the proper features is the most important step. Using raw data file will probably not work.
2) You need to use an svm tool. LIBSVM (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is one of the best tools. 
3) If you read the document (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf), you will see that scaling usually improves SVM performance.